# hive explain plan generation

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

As we know that explain followed by query in hive gives us the explain plan for that query as an output, is it possible to get the explain plan in any form of data structure instead of a text format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the output as JSON using `FORMATTED`. You can try:

`EXPLAIN FORMATTED query`

This should give you the explain output in JSON format.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! But it gets difficult to convert the obtained json file into a java object as the output changes for each query, json for different queries does not contain the same of number of attributes. Hence, can you please suggest how to overcome this?

Comment: It sounds like i've answered your question. You now have a different question around marshalling json in to a java object i would say.